# Perl P4 module flags passing

Tags: perl, perforce

I'm using the P4 module in Perl in order to add files to the repository:

```
$p4->Run('add', $filename);
```

But I want to specify the change-list name as in regular shell command:

```
p4 add [-c changelist] filename
```

In short I want to know how I pass flags.

Thanks

Comment: What exact module are you using?

Comment: This is a legacy in a script I found `use P4;`

Answer (score 1):

I know this is Quick & Dirty but could you not just use

```
system "p4 add -c $changelist $filename";
```

If you use "" this will interpolate the variables within perl, what i assume is what you need.

Comment: Gnah, curse my stupid german autocorrecting IE at work. And i just copy/pasted the shell command he specified.

Comment: I know, i kept them because they are in the question and it is still optional wether or not to use that argument in the script. But i admit, once in syntax it looks like i sugested to Keep them in the implementation. I removed them as the question specified that he actually wanted to use the -c.

Comment: I have other scripts utilizing that particular solution, but I stumbled upon this module and wanted to learn something new

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```perl
$p4->Run('add', '-c', $changelist, $filename);
```

The [P4Perl API docs for the Run method](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4script/02_perl.html#1048005) don't explicitly say how to pass options. However, there are examples in the rest of the docs that show option passing (`$p4->RunSubmit( "-r", $change );` for example.)

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work at all. How is it supposed to pair the arguments with the flags?

Answer (score 0):

I used the following template at the end:

```
$change = $p4->FetchChange();
$change->{ 'Description' } = "Some description";
$p4->RunSubmit( "-r", $change );
```

It also submits the files